# When do we say "I change the bed" and "I change the bedding"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

According to my study, "**change the bedding**" seems bigger than "**change the bed**".

So, I asked Chatgpt

Chatgpt says

> When you say "I change the bed every week," you are likely referring
> to changing the sheets, pillowcases, and possibly other items that
> directly touch the body, such as blankets or duvet covers.
>
> When you say "I change the bedding every week," you are referring to a
> more comprehensive task that involves not only changing the sheets and
> pillowcases, but also possibly washing or replacing other items that
> are part of the bed, such as the mattress pad, bed skirt, or
> decorative shams. This phrase suggests a more thorough cleaning and
> maintenance of the entire bed.

But, from the information in the dictionaries, I think there is a simpler explanation. "**Change the bed**" might refer to change the sheet or the bed cover, but not blankets or pillow covers

and "**change the bedding**" might refer to change the sheet or the bed cover, and also blankets or pillow covers.

> change a bed = change the sheets on a bed [=remove dirty sheets from a
> bed and replace them with clean ones]
>
> bedding noun /ˈbedɪŋ/ /ˈbedɪŋ/ [uncountable] the sheets and covers
> that you put on a bed, and often also the mattress and the pillows

When do we say "**I change the bed**" and "**I change the bedding**"?

Comment: What do you mean by "seems bigger"? That *change the bed/bedding* entails more work than *change the bed/bedding* or what? And by the way, you wrote "change the bedding" ***twice*** in the same sentence.

Comment: Chatgtp is talking out of its arse. Changing the bed[s] and changing the bedding are just two different ways of saying the same thing. But ***bedding*** is far more common for this context.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems likely it's only being asked because of something chatgpt (incorrectly) said. Confirming or refuting assertions made by LLMs is (or at least, imho *should* be) Off Topic

Comment: In your first sentence, you have "change the bedding" twice. Which did you mean is "bigger"?

Comment: Don't use ChatGPT as a source of information. if it doesn't know, it will just make something up. You can **never** trust it to provide accurate information. It's just a chatbot, not a source of knowledge.

Comment: Third and last time, you've written ***change the bedding*** TWICE in the introduction. Which is it, *change the bed* is "bigger" than *change the bedding* or vice versa?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/339091/when-do-we-say-i-change-the-bed-and-i-change-the-bedding#comment648163_33909

Comment: @Mari-LouA, you can just figure it out easily. "change the bedding" seems to cover more things than "change the bed"

Comment: For pete's sake: I change the sheets every week. Generally, we don't say "change the bed". That chatcrap is just that.

Comment: FumbleFingers I'm not sure I'm entirely with you. And Lambie is speaking as an American, where they possibly only "change the bed" when they buy a new one and send the old to the scrap heap. In between times they "change the sheets". To me "changing the bed" is the routine change of sheets once a week or however often deemed proper. "Changing the bedding" does suggest to me the sort of occasional thing you do eg. in spring, when you put away your autumn duvet and get out the more lightweight summer version. But I have no doubt this will vary from one family to another and possibly by region.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, right. Change the bedding, though, I agree.

Comment: Where does the second block quote come from? It doesn't seem like something that ChatGPT would write.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, from the dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Change the bed" is just an idiomatic way of saying "change the bedding" (the sheets, the pillow covers, duvet covers etc). A similar example is how "change the baby" is an idiomatic way of saying "change the baby's diaper/nappy". Really, there is no difference. If "change the bed" were *literal*, it would mean surely mean exchanging every part of the bed frame!

As a native British English speaker, I don't agree with what you got from Chat GPT at all. For a start, not every bed has things like a 'bed skirt' (these are considered quite old fashioned). And extras like 'mattress pads' (which is a very broad term and could be anything from something to protect your mattress against incontinence to a mattress 'topper', which some feel adds extra comfort) and 'decorative shams' are not necessarily changed with bedding anyway, if ever (mattress toppers may last as long as a mattress).

Comment: A person on Quora here says "I may be pedantic but, when I change the bed, I put a new sheet on it. When I change the bedding, I take a shovel and remove the sawdust and chicken shit from the coop. The bedding is all that whatever rests on it rests on. You can consider that to mean the whole mattress, the hay, the sawdust, etc. If you change the bed, the bed stays put and what is on the bed gets replaced.", which is similar to what I guess!

Comment: I would never ever say change the bed. I say change the sheets for that.

Comment: @lambie Cool story! People do say it, though.

Comment: Even so, it's amazing that no one said change the sheets. Change the bed may be British but it is not used in the States.

Comment: @Lambie but Americans do say "change the baby", so it can't be that unusual. You also say "put the baby down", instead of "down *to sleep*", or "*to bed*". Sounds like you're taking it to the vets to be euthanized.

Comment: change the baby is not the same thing. Aren't you English?? Change the baby and change the bed are not the same thing.

Comment: @Lambie British.

Comment: I agree entirely that "change the bed" is a British idiom, not dissimilar to "change the baby". I think it may emerge out of domestic service. In great houses like Downton Abbey, certain maids might be assigned on eg. a Friday to "change the beds".

Answer (score 1):

To my Canadian ears, there's a difference similar to what ChatGPT has told you.

"Change the bed" is what you normally do every week or so when you replace the used sheets with clean ones.

"Change the bedding" is what do you do when there's some need to change the bed clothes other than regular use, like if the bed has been soiled and needs to be immediately changed because it's unusable, or because the seasons have changed and you need lighter or heavier bed clothes.

Comment: This agrees with my (British) understanding entirely. But I would suggest there are other circumstances in which  you might  "change the bedding"when you change from winter to summer weight blamkets, duvet etc - or any time, for whatever reason you intend to do more than simply change the sheets.

Comment: @WS2 Agreed, and thanks. I've updated both definitions